# if packagist says master build failing, If I install package with composer, will it work?

Tags: composer-php, phpoffice

I'm kinda new to using composer (but I think it is awesome) so please pardon the noob question.

Folks are requesting exports fancier than csv so I thought I'd install phpOffice excel using composer.  But, the master is 'build failing' and the develop is 'build error'.  An I correct in assuming the master build failed means I should not install this with composer because it won't work?

In researching this I also found phpOffice spreadsheet, but that appears to be in development still.

Any other alternatives if I cannot use phpOffice excel due to the build status issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what package you are talking about, if the builds for any of the branches are failing it just means that the builds for any of the branches are failing, that's it.

The `master` and `develop` branches may be well ahead of the latest tag, and chances are the maintainers are experimenting with it, and working towards a passing build again.

If you trust the maintainers *not* to release broken software, then it's safe to use one of the tagged versions, so for example, run

```
$ composer require phpoffice/phpexcel:^1.8.1
```

to install the latest stable version.

**Note** It appears that `phpoffice/phpexcel:1.8.1` has been released on 2015-05-01; quite some time has passed since. Whether or not this package works for you, then, is something you have to find out for yourself.

For reference, see:

- https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel